# How to perform a switch statement on a generic type in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, switch-statement

I'm having some troubles to check the proper type on a switch statement. I have these classes that extends from `Exception`

```
public abstract class DomainException<T>: Exception
{
    public readonly DomainExceptionCodes Code;
    public readonly T Metadata;

    public DomainException(DomainExceptionCodes code, T metadata): base(message: code.GetEnumDescription())
    {
        Code = code;
        Metadata = metadata;
    }
}

public class EmptyFieldsException : DomainException<EmptyFieldsMetadata>
{
    public EmptyFieldsException(EmptyFieldsMetadata metadata) : base(code: DomainExceptionCodes.EmptyField, metadata)
    {
    }
}
```

Let's asume there is a bunch of derived classes. What I need to do, is to be able to manage all of the derived clases in the same way when handling the exception.

Something like:

```
try{
    // code that raise the exception
}
catch (Exception e) {
   // some code here
   switch(e) {
       case DomainException:
            // do something
            break;
       default:
            //other code here
            break;
   }
}
```

However, because `DomainException` requires at least one argument for the generic type it's raising an error

[image]

I tried with `object` and `dynamic`, but then the type does not match

[image]

Any clues?

Comment: It's the same problem `catch (DomainException e)` will require an argument for the generic type, and `dynamic` and `object` won't match. I don't want to have a `catch` or a `case` for every derived class. I want to use the base class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately for your problem, that's not how generics work in .NET. The generic type argument is not erased, so `A<T>` is *not* `A<object>` (which would of course violate type safety!).

If you can change the definition of `DomainException<T>`, the best solution would be to add an intermediate non-generic type:

```
class DomainException: Exception
{
  public readonly DomainExceptionCodes Code;
}

class DomainException<T>: DomainException
{
  public T Metadata;
}
```

Then you can just catch the non-generic exception to get the code, and only need the generic variant to access the metadata (which presumably means you already know what type to expect there).

If you *can't* change the exception definition, unfortunately your only recourse is to use reflection. Something like this should work:

```
try
{
  ...
}
catch (Exception ex) 
  when (
        ex.GetType().IsGenericType 
        && ex.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DomainException<>)
      )
{
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, in this case even to access the code, you'll need to use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029942/can-you-catch-a-exceptiont-where-t-is-any-type) SO question, you can't rally catch all types at once.
The code below (taken from the other question) should do what you need.

```
// ...

catch (FaultException ex)
{
    Type exceptionType = ex.GetType();

    if (exceptionType.IsGenericType)
    {
        // Find the type of the generic parameter
        Type genericType = ex.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();

        if (genericType != null)
        {
            // TODO: Handle the generic type.
        }
    }
}
```